# retorno de vários erro via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

estou com um probleminha em ralação ao retorno de erros via ajax, segue o condigo:

Index.php

```
        <h4>Cadastro de Nome</h4>
                <form id="cadUsuario" method="post">
                    <label>Nome:</label><input required type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
                    <br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" id="salvar" />
                </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {    
$("#cadUsuario").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  url: "salvar.php",
  dataType: "json", // Add datatype
  data: form_data
}).done(function (data) {
 var mensagem = '';

 if (!data.insert){
    mensagem = 'Falha no cadastro';
 }

 if(!data.email){
    mensagem += 'Falha no envio do email';
 }

 if(data.insert && data.email){
    mensagem = 'Operação realizda com sucesso';
 }

 alert(mensagem);
}, "json");
}); 
});
```

Salvar.php

```
    <?php
include "config.php";
if((isset($_POST['nome'])&&$_POST['nome']!="")){ 
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `nomes` (`idnomes`,`nomes`) VALUES (NULL,'$nome')";

require('mail_config.php');

$resultado = array('insert' => false, 'email' => false); 

$resultado['insert'] = mysql_query($sql);
$resultado['email'] = sendMail("Testando o Mailer","Mensagem de teste do Mailer com Ajax".$nome."","androclesleite@gmail.com","Jefferson Androcles");

echo json_encode($resultado);
}
```

mail_config.php

```
<?php function sendMail($assunto,$msg,$destino,$nomeDestino) {
require_once('Mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                 
$mail->Host       = 'host';     
$mail->Port       = '587';                   
$mail->Username   = 'androcles@androcles.com.br'; 
$mail->Password   = 'Senha';         
$mail->From = 'androcles@androcles.com.br';
$mail->FromName = 'AndroclesMail';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = utf8_decode($assunto);
$mail->Body    = utf8_decode($msg);
$mail->AddAddress($destino,utf8_decode($nomeDestino) );
if(!$mail->Send()){
echo '<span>Erro ao enviar, favor entre em contato pelo e-mail suporte@suporte.com.br!</span>';
}else{
}
}
?>
```

Até então está tudo funcionando, menos o erro 2 (existe => 2), eu faço o erro propositalmente mas não me retorna nada, os outros dois, ou seja, o 1 e o 3 funciona normal, podem me ajudar? e queria saber se tem algum erro no jquery se é uma gambiarra ou não kkkk, Obrigado!

Comment: O if `$MailEnv === false` não deveria ser separado? os outros dois if comparam coisas diferentes ... pense no cenário que o insert falhou e o email foi enviado com sucesso.

Comment: é então, to pensando isso aí agora! vou testa sua resposta abaixo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O if está comparando coisa diferentes (insert realizado ou não e o envio de email) e usa apenas um 'balde' (array de retorno) para jogar o resultado.

```
if($query === false){
    echo json_encode(array('existe' => 1));
} elseif ($MailEnv === false) {
    echo json_encode(array('existe' => 2));
}elseif ($query === true){
    echo json_encode(array('existe' => 3));
}
```

Minha sugestão para resolver isso é criar um array que tenha o resultado das duas operações e depois passado ao javascript via `json_encode()`. Parti do ponto que `sendMail()` retorna um boolean.

```
require('mail_config.php');

$resultado = array('insert' => false, 'email' => false); 

$resultado['insert'] = mysql_query($sql);
$resultado['email'] = sendMail("Testando o Mailer","Mensagem de teste do Mailer com Ajax".$nome."","androclesleite@gmail.com","Jefferson Androcles");

echo json_encode($resultado);
```

A responsabilidade de verificar se tudo certo ou não agora é feita pelo javascript.

```
.done(function (data) {
    var mensagem = '';

     if (!data.insert){
        mensagem = 'Falha no cadastro';
     }

     if(!data.email){
        mensagem += 'Falha no envio do email';
     }

     if(data.insert && data.email){
        mensagem = 'Operação realizda com sucesso';
     }

     alert(mensagem);
}
```

Comment: Fala que deu falha no envio do email, mas o email é enviado!

Comment: @JeffersonAndrocles da um `console.log()` em `data` veja os valores pode colocar aqui nos comentários.

Comment: não sei se ajuda mas o link é esse, http://htcompanyonline.com.br/Teste/

Comment: não trabalho muito com jquery, mas seria assim,   
.done(function (data) {
     console.log()
  alert(data);
    }, "json");
 por que se for, aparece object Object

Comment: @JeffersonAndrocles assim: `console.log(data)` aí no console do navegador (geralmente ativado pelo F12) vão aparecer os valores.

Comment: Object {insert: true, email: null}, acho que o erro ta no mail_config.php, vou editar minha pergunta e posta-lo!

Comment: @JeffersonAndrocles isso, também verifique se o `SendMail()` retorna algo.

Comment: Acho que o problema está depois que voce envia o email, pois nao está retornando nada para a propriedade email do json que voce envia pra tela de novo.

Comment: Neste trecho voce espera um retorno do método "SendMail", pra atribuir o resultado para a propriedade "email":

$resultado['email'] = sendMail("Testando o Mailer","Mensagem de teste do Mailer com Ajax".$nome."","androclesleite@gmail.com","Jefferson Androcles");

Porém no método sendMail voce nao retorna nada:

if(!$mail->Send()){
echo '<span>Erro ao enviar, favor entre em contato pelo e-mail suporte@suporte.com.br!</span>';
}else{
}

Nao deveria ter um return "email enviado com sucesso" ou "houve um problema", ou algo do tipo?

Comment: é então, era isso mesmo! PERFEITO, muito obrigado!